# Illustrator Fill in Paths that Cross

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, fill

I have created paths in Illustrator. I have one path, see image, that crosses itself. It produces this white box inside. How do I fill it with the same black. Everything I tried seems to be rather a stupid workaround, like just putting a box behind it. This path has also a stroke that is important in other parts of the image. What to do?

[image: How to fill in this section]

Edit: These are my points and that Non Zero Winding Order button did remove the box once I made it bigger. Can I somehow remove the stroke showing up here? I need the stroke for other parts of the image, but not here.

[image]

Comment: But this has fixed the issue you asked about. Your original image does not show anything about your stroke. All yiou new need to do is make the stroke color be none.

Comment: Yes, It did indeed. But i need the stroke for other parts of that picture (not shown here). Can I remove the stroke somehow from this overlapping section only?

Comment: Use shape builder to build the actual shape.

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With object in question selected. Open **Window → Attributes**. Choose show all form the hamburger menu of this window (if its not showing all*). And click on the **Non Zero Winding Order** button, it looks ike what you want, the other button (even odd winding rule) looks like what you have now. Done.

* *Protip*: Make all panels show all at all times, you might discover something useful eventually.

Comment: That button doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @Dimitri Then your image does not cross itself it just appears to cross itself. Show us the points.

Comment: Alright, I updated the question and posted the image.